# android webview don't support async js function

Tags: javascript, android, webview, async-await

I try to load a simple html in android webview. In the html file , it include a script like this, the method with "async".

```
<script >
    async function test(){
        alert("test");
    }
    test();
</script>
```

I found that, the "alert" doesn't run ok in all kinds of android version devices.
The test result: (The app is run in android simulator)

- android6.0 (23)：Not Ok
- android7.0 (24)：Not Ok
- android7.1.1 (25)：OK
- android8.0：OK

Can anyone help to solve the problem ?  I try to compare java.android.webkit package between android7.0 and android8.0, but i can't find any useful info.
Please help.thanks

Comment: Hello. Do you find answer? I have some problem

Answer (score 0):

You can see the compatibility of JavaScript async keyword in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#browser_compatibility

WebView Android starts to support it from 55.
I don't know how to check WebView version but I checked my version from chrome://inspect/#devices, which was 53.0.2785.124.

I was using Android 7.0, API 24. As you found out in your question, my device did not support async keyword.

Unfortunately we can't overcome this limitation.